# How to update Temperature and Humidity data from Server using after method Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, inheritance, time

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
class MainWindow:

    def __init__(self, master, title, size):
        self.master = master
        self.title = title
        self.size = size
        self.master.title(self.title)
        self.master.geometry(self.size)
        self.widgets()
    def widgets(self):

        self.heading = Label(self.master,
                             text="Temperature & Humidity from ESP32").place(x=150, y=10)

        self.addbutton = Button(self.master,
                                text="+ ADD NEW DEVICE",
                                width=20,
                                command=self.add_button_clicked)
        self.addbutton.place(x=200, y=50)

    def add_button_clicked(self):
        obj = AddNewDeviceWindow(self, "add new device", "600x600")

class AddNewDeviceWindow(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent, title, size):
        super().__init__(name='add_new_device')

        self.parent = parent

        self.title(title)

        self.size = size

        self.geometry(size)

        self.label = Label(self, text="Enter ID Here").pack(pady=10)

        self.entry = Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack(pady=10)

        self.add_button = Button(self,
                                 text="Add",
                                 command=lambda:[self.get_ip_data(),self.destroy()]).pack(pady=10)
    def get_ip_data(self):
        ip = self.entry.get()
        response = requests.get(f"http://{ip}/")
        data = response.json()
        print(data)
        temp = round(data['temperature'], 2)
        hum = round(data['humidity'], 2)
        self.label=Label(text="Device 1").place(x=270, y=120)
        self.button = Button(text=f"Temperature: {temp}°C\nHumidity: {hum} %",
                             width=20, bg="green", fg="white").place(x=200, y=150)

        self.after(2000, self.get_ip_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainWindow = Tk()
    mainFenster = MainWindow(mainWindow, "ESP32 Temperature & Humidity Measurement", "600x600")
    mainWindow.mainloop()
```

My need is When I click "Add new device button" then it shows the temperature and humidity values in "self.button" which is created under "get_ip_data" function and it automatically updates the data from server after 5 second. But when I run this code it cannot update automatically.Please suggest me some ideas to solve this issue.

Comment: My recommendation is to stop using lambda the way that you are. Create a proper function to call from the button. Functions are far easier to write, understand, and debug.